# Handle if/else more dynamically

Tags: c#

I need suggestions how to handle this more dynamically as of of now if you see below code , i am hardcoding findText[0] and findText[1] but later findText value can grow and i dont know how many values it will have, in that case how many index are there i will not know.

i know using foreach loop this situation can be handled, but problem is suppose i have two values "abc,xyz" abc is the first value so suppose if abc is not found in line it will go to else part and it will append the line to stringbuilder , now when next value come "xyz" and it is found in line it will again get appended. so how to handle this ? In order to handle this i used findtext[0] and findtext[1] approach but this will not work in all scenarios.

```
   foreach (string fText in findText.Split(','))
    {
    if (line.IndexOf(fText , StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) //line.Contains(findText)
         {
              Regex regexText = new Regex(findText[0], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
              line = regexText.Replace(line, "<span style =\"background-color: #FFFF00\">" + findText[0] + " </span>");
              builder.Append(line);
         }
else
         {
              builder.Append(line);
              builder.Append("<br/>");
         }
    }
```

Used approach as of now -

```
string[] findText = ("suspicious,suspcious").Split(',') ;
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{

   if (line.IndexOf(findText[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) //line.Contains(findText)
     {
          Regex regexText = new Regex(findText[0], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          line = regexText.Replace(line, "<span style =\"background-color: #FFFF00\">" + findText[0] + " </span>");
          builder.Append(line);
     }
   if (line.IndexOf(findText[1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) //line.Contains(findText)
     {
          Regex regexText = new Regex(findText[1], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
          line = regexText.Replace(line, "<span style =\"background-color: #FFFF00\">" + findText[1] + " </span>");
          builder.Append(line);
     }
   else
     {
          builder.Append(line);
          builder.Append("<br/>");
     }

}
```

Comment: will you always have a comma between values?

Comment: Yes always comma will be there

Comment: If you are reading html, why don't you use `HtmlAgilityPack`?

Comment: I am converting csv/txt file to html , can i use Agilitypack for this and show in browser ?

Comment: Yes. https://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the content of the conditional blocks appears to be the same, you could use LINQ to find the first match, like this:

```
var find = findText.FirstOrDefault(t => line.IndexOf(t, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
if (find != null) {
    Regex regexText = new Regex(find, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    line = regexText.Replace(line, "<span style =\"background-color: #FFFF00\">" + find + " </span>");
    builder.Append(line);
} else {
    builder.Append(line);
    builder.Append("<br/>");
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` would yield the initial match or a `null`, letting you choose what line to append.

Comment: At first line of code it gives error - cannot convert from System.StringComparison to int

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] finds = findText.Split(',');

                bool found = false;
                foreach (string find in finds)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, find, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        Regex regexText = new Regex(find, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        line = regexText.Replace(line, "<span style =\"background-color: #FFFF00\">" + find + " </span>");
                        builder.Append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found)
                {
                    builder.Append(line);
                    builder.Append("<br/>");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Edit, forgot to set found = true; in my loop

Comment: Your code does not satisfy my test case and it appends the line two times - suppose i have two values "abc,xyz" abc is the first value so suppose if abc is not found in line it will go to else part and it will append the line to stringbuilder , now when next value come "xyz" and it is found in line it will again get appended.So the condition should be like check "abc" -> not found -> check "xyz" not found add now. how i can achieve that, this is my original problem ?

Comment: ahh, I understand now. One sec

Comment: although I think I may be misunderstanding again

Comment: @user662285 so you only want the <br/> if you don't find anything right?

Comment: @user662285 and you only want the first found match / replace to be run?

Comment: input abc,xyz to your code. first it will match abc in line not found it will execute if(!found) part and line will be appended, now second value is xyz now suppose xyz is found in the line it will execute if part and append the same line again. So ideally what should happen is check "abc" -> not found -> check "xyz" found , now execute if(!found) part

Comment: I don't have an else. I have an if not found AFTER the loop finished

Comment: Sorry.. i mean it will execute your if(!found) instead of else

Comment: input abc,xyz to your code. first it will match abc in line not found it will execute if(!found) part and line will be appended, now second value is xyz now suppose xyz is found in the line it will execute if part and append the same line again. So ideally what should happen is check "abc" -> not found -> check "xyz" found , now execute if(!found) part

Comment: yeah but I set found = true; when I find something, so then the if (!found) wont be executed

Comment: So the problem is suppose i have line as "•Remove data collection checklist questions about Suspicious Activities" , first run value is "suspcious" it is not found and it will go to if(!found) and append it now in second run value is "suspicious" which will match and execute the if part and it will append to the builder, hence duplicate line will be inserted. I want to avoid this if you see my code in the post i have done hardcoding of findtext[0] and [1] in order to avoid this but this will not work when i will values greater than or less than 2. Hope you understand the problem now.

Comment: you are incorrect here. I do not go to if (!found) until after I have checked ALL finds

Comment: Please run your code with input parameters and line mentioned